# Can DXErrorProvider set different error type for different DataAnnotation/Validator attributes?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, devexpress

I have base class that checks controls validation.

```
  Validator.TryValidateObject(ds, new ValidationContext(ds), res, true);
```

gives me set of errors that particular data source bound to my controls returned.

That is fine, but DXErrorProvider can also set Type of error for example "warning".

Is there any way that I can set particular error type according to validation attributes in my Data Object?

For now I have achieved it by reflection and checking names of my attributes but this solution seems to be more complex and inefficient that it could be.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a automated way. As you can read [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDXErrorProviderDXErrorProvidertopic) the DXErrorProvider is totaly based on the interface `IDXDataErrorInfo`. If you are using DataAnnotations just with the error icon you won't need the DXErrorProvider, because this is handled by the controls itself. So if you want to use custom icons you could mix this to ways of errorhandling. For example you could do sth. like this:

```
public class MyClass : IDXDataErrorInfo
{
   [Range(0,100)]
   [//Further custom validation]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   //Implement the Interface for your DXErrorProvider
   public void GetPropertyError(string propertyname, ErrorInfo info)
   {
      List<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

      if (propertyname.Equals(nameof(Id))
      {
        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(Id, new ValidationContext(this,null,null), errors))
        {
            string errorText = string.Empty;
            errors.ForEach(e => errorText += e.ErrorMessage);

            //This type set's the error-icon
            info.ErrorType = //The Type you want ErrorType.Warning for example
            info.ErrorText = errorText;
        }
      }
    }
       
       public void GetError(ErrorInfo info) {}  
}
```

You could also write a descendant from ValidationResult which consists of a Property `ErrorType` to handle your validation logic completly in your DataAnnotations. Just one possible solution which I think works pretty well.